# PineScript - Is possible to put a comment with a variable inside?

Tags: pine-script

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
strategy.close('LONG', when=shortCond, comment="Exit BTCUSDT price={{close}}")
```

And the result that I want is the Alert with the following message: Exit BTCUSDT price=60201.
Anyone knows if it is doable?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Write your message in "Create Alert" window:
   [image]

Then it would show up like this:

[image]

2. Use `alert_message` property in your `strategy` calls.

Example:

```
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, when=longCondition, alert_message="Price: "+str.tostring(close))
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, when=shortCondition, alert_message="Price: "+str.tostring(close))
```

If you go with this solution, you need to write {{strategy.order.alert_message}} as message.

[image]

And it would show up like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In version 5:

```
strategy.close('LONG', when=shortCond, comment="Exit BTCUSDT " + str.tostring(close) + "blah blah blah" + str.tostring(AnotherCustomVariable))
```

You get the picture. This method can be used with any comment function.

P.S., Don't forget to close the parenthesis of the `strategy.close` function at the end (notice the double parenthesis) or you'll get an error.